# Understanding #define preprocessor directive macro syntax

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor, lpc

The following code is taken from the LPC54618.h header file:

```
typedef struct {
     //...structure elements
     __IO uint32_t SDIOCLKSEL;
     //...more elements

} SYSCON_Type;

#define SYSCON_BASE         (0x40000000u)
#define SYSCON              ((SYSCON_Type *)SYSCON_BASE)
```

1. As far as I can guess the meaning behind the line

   `#define SYSCON              ((SYSCON_Type *)SYSCON_BASE)`

I would assume that it creates a pointer named `SYSCON` that points to a variable of type `SYSCON_Type` which is stored at the address `0x40000000u`. Is this really what happens? And is there any ressource that explains the syntax that is being used here (i.e. defining pointers inside macros)?

2. When I try to alter the value of SDIOCLKSEL directly, i.e.:

   `SYSCON->SDIOCLKSEL = some value;`

   I get an error:

   `error: expected ')'
   error: expected parameter declarator
   error: expected ')'
   error: expected function body after function declarator`

but if I use it inside a function, e.g.:

```
void foo(void)
{
   SYSCON->SDIOCLKSEL = some value;  
}
```

there is no error. Why is that? Why can't I write directly to the structure?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to show the code which doesn't compile in context.  A single line by itself doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: You can't have generic statements outside of functions. Any book, tutorial or class should have taught you that.

Comment: As far as the preprocessor is concerned, the `#define` means that `SYSCON` is now a constant that expands to `((SYSCON_Type *)0x40000000u)`, so writing `SYSCON->SDIOCLKSEL = some value;` is exactly equivalent to writing `((SYSCON_Type *)0x40000000u)->SDIOCLKSEL = some value;`. All the rest is just C syntax, unrelated to the preprocessor.

Comment: Keep in mind you can also just have the compiler show you the output of the preprocessor to help understand what's going on. Check your compiler's documentation for how to do that.

Comment: Preprocessor does not know anything about pointers. Therefore there is no syntax for pointer definition in macros. It is the same syntax as without macros.

Comment: @All
thanks for your comments guys, much appreciated!
@Gerhardh
I guess this is were I lack most understanding then. The syntax I have learned thus far for declaring pointers is the simple `int *foo_ptr = &foo;`.  How `((SYSCON_Type *)0x40000000u)` translates into that still eludes me.

Comment: Your compiler errors are simply for trying to write executable code outside any function (at file scope), which isn't valid C. You can have variable/function declarations/definitions there, but not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define SYSCON_BASE         (0x40000000u)
```

This simply lists that at the physical address `0x40000000`.

```
#define SYSCON ((SYSCON_Type *)SYSCON_BASE)
```

This converts the integer constant `0x40000000u` to a pointer to struct by means of a cast. It doesn't actually allocate anything - the actual registers are already allocated as memory-mapped hardware.

Simply put, it says "at address 0x40000000 there's a hardware peripheral `SYSCON`" (whatever that is, some timer?). It's a common scenario that you have several hardware peripherals of the same type inside a MCU (many SPI, ADC etc), each with the same register layout, but found at different addresses. We can use the same struct type for each such peripheral, and also the same driver code.

The struct itself will have a memory map which corresponds 100% to the register layout. Here it is important to ensure that padding/alignment doesn't screw things up, but hopefully the MCU manufacturer have thought of that (don't take it for granted though).

Assuming `SDIOCLKSEL` has a register offset of `0x10`, then when you type `SYSCON->SDIOCLKSEL = some value;`, you get machine code like this (pseudo assembler code):

```
LOAD 0x40000000 into index register X  
LOAD 0x10 into register A
ADD A to X
MOVE some value into the address of X
```

(ARM got special instructions that can move etc based on an offset, so it may be fewer instructions in the actual machine code. Subsequent register accesses could keep "X" untouched and use that base address repeatedly, for effective code.)

The `__IO` qualifier is just code bloat hiding `volatile`.

The reason why you get an error when you try to "write directly into the structure" is simply that you can't execute code outside all functions, it has nothing to do with this struct.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy.

> that it creates a pointer named SYSCON that points to a variable of
>   type SYSCON_Type which is stored at the address 0x40000000u. Is this
>   really what happens?

Yes and no. When you use the macro SYSCON

```
void foo(uint32_t value)
{
   SYSCON->SDIOCLKSEL = value;
}
```

preprocessor converts into:

```
void foo(uint32_t value)
{
  ((SYSCON_Type *)0x40000000u)->SDIOCLKSEL = value;
}
```

which writes the 32bit unsigned `value` to the memory location at the address 0x40000000u + the offset of the struct member.

It is usually used to access the harware registers mapped in the memory address space.

You need to do it inside the function (as all code in the C language)

Comment: I guess this is were I lack most understanding then. The syntax I have learned thus far for declaring pointers is the simple `int *foo_ptr = &foo;`.

How 

`((SYSCON_Type *)0x40000000u)` translates into that still eludes me

Comment: @Vincent, there is no declaration of a pointer *variable* here.  There is only an integer constant converted to a pointer *value*, which is then dereferenced.  The success of this approach depends on knowledge of the target hardware (so that the right constant can be selected), and cooperation of the C implementation in use (since the effect is implementation-defined).  With that said, it is relatively common practice in programming for embedded devices.